# How to scrape html in python with bs4 and save data to csv

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am looking to extract data from a website and save it in a clean format to csv. Currently my code is not running and returning the error: "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'writerow'"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import csv
url="http://www.covers.com/pageLoader/pageLoader.aspx?page=/data/nfl/injury/injuries.html"

arr=[[],[],[],[],[]]

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
    s = url.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
    tables = soup.find_all("table", class_="data")
    for table in tables:
       teams=table.find_all("td", class_="datahead")
       teamName=teams[0].text
       rrows=table.find_all("tr")
       for rrow in rrows:
           ccols=rrow.find_all("td")
           if len(ccols)>3:
               name=ccols[0].text
               pos=ccols[1].text    
               status=ccols[2].text
               desc=ccols[3].text
               arr[0].append(teamName)
               arr[1].append(name)
               arr[2].append(pos)
               arr[3].append(status)
               arr[4].append(desc)

with open('injuries.csv', 'w', newline='') as datafile:
    a=csv.writer(datafile, delimiter=',')
    for a in range(1000):
        a.writerow([arr[0][a],arr[1][a],arr[2][a],arr[3][a],arr[4][a]])
    datafile.close
```

Any explanation as to why this error is caused would be greatly appreciated

Comment: change `wr=csv.writer(datafile, delimiter=',')` and `wr.writerow(...`, you are using `a` for both the write object and in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You use `a` both as a loop variable and name of `csv.writer` object. Replace `for a in range(1000)` with `for i in range(1000)` and `arr[0][a]` with `arr[0][i]` and so on.

Comment: why the downvotes for this and mine? They are the right answer

Answer (score 0):

In

```
a=csv.writer(datafile, delimiter=',')
for a in range(1000):
```

You're using `a` as the `csv.writer` and then immediately using it as an index. Change one of them.